# Why is $I$ the only idempotent matrix with nonzero determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant, idempotents

While reading about the attribute of the identity Matrix, it's mentioned that I is not only idempotent but that it is also the only such matrix that does not have a determinant of zero. While I being idempotent is simple to understand, how is it proved that every other matrix without a determinant of zero isn't?

Comment: One way to view idempotents in general (e.g. idempotents in rings) is by analogy of a function that is the identity on a subspace and zero on the "complement" of said subspace. So in some sense the space separates into two pieces, one where the idempotent is identity and one where it is zero. With this dichotomy, we can intuit that the matrix in the posted example has to be the identity everywhere, since the subspace where it is $0$ is trivial by invertibility.

Answer (score 17):

Asserting that $A$ is idempotent means that $A^2=A$. But, if $A$ is invertible, then$$\operatorname{Id}=A^{-1}A=A^{-1}A^2=A.$$

Answer (score 1):

$A^2=A \implies A(A-\mathcal{I}_2) = \mathcal{O}_2 $, and since $\text{det}(A)\neq 0$, it follows that $A-\mathcal{I}_2 = \mathcal{O}_2$, i.e. $A$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Idempotent means

$$M^2 = M$$ Which means $$(M-I) M = 0.$$ So, if the determinant of $M$ is not $0,$ $M-I$ must be singular, so there must be a vector $v$ such that $Mv = v.$ Now, consider the orthogonal complement of $v.$ The matrix is still idempotent on that, so do it by induction.